# XSLT for merging multiple xml documents in BPEL

Tags: wso2

This is regarding xml transformation within BPEL. 
In my bpel process, data is coming from two separate sources (partnerLinks). 
Data from both sources is in the same xml format. 
I need to combine the data from the two XML documents into one xml document and then pass it back to the ESB. 
I was trying with bpel:doXslTransform()). 
I am not sure how to pass the two responses from the partnerLinks to this function in a single call.

I tried concatenating the two responses into a string within a message type variable and then pass this to the bpel:doXslTransform(). Is this the right approach to merge the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do a bpel:doXslTransform here.

This involves receiving an XML document from one service, converting it to a different Schema to form a new request message, and sending the new request to another service. Such documentation conversion can be accomplished using XSLT via the bpel:doXslTransform function.

```
<variables>
   <variable name="A" element="foo:AElement" />
   <variable name="B" element="bar:BElement" />
</variables>
...
<sequence>
   <invoke ... inputVariable="..." outputVariable="A" />
   <assign>
      <copy>
         <from>
            bpel:doXslTransform("urn:stylesheets:A2B.xsl", $A)
         </from>
         <to variable="B" />
      </copy>
   </assign>
   <invoke ... inputVariable="B" ... />
</sequence>
```

Please refer http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/OS/wsbpel-v2.0-OS.html for further information.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Am looking into the schema approach. Will update with the findings.